# Example of functions in $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Could anyone come up with an example of functions in $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

---

When $n=1$, there is nothing to say. I don't see an immediate example for $n>2$.

This is motivated by the following remark in Evans's Partial Differential Equations. The notation $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ suggests that there must some nonintegrable functions in $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in general.

> [image]

Comment: Did you mean not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @JackyChong: Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the example
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|^{3/2}}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{dx}{1+|x|^{3/2}} =\int^\infty_0 \int_{|x|=r}\frac{1}{1+r^{3/2}}\ dSdr = C \int^\infty_0 \frac{r^{n-1}}{1+r^{3/2}}\ dr =\infty
\end{align}
since $n\geq 2$.

Next, observe
\begin{align}
\nabla f = -\frac{3}{2}\frac{x}{|x|^{1/2}(1+|x|^{3/2})^2}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
|\nabla f| = \frac{3}{2} \frac{|x|^{1/2}}{(1+|x|^{3/2})^2}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{dx}{(1+|x|^{3/2})^n} = \int^\infty_0 \int_{|x|=r} \frac{1}{(1+r^{3/2})^n}\ dSdr = C\int^\infty_0\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r^{3/2})^n}\ dr <\infty
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|x|^{n/2}dx}{(1+|x|^{3/2})^{2n}} = C\int^\infty_0 \frac{r^{3n/2-1}}{(1+r^{3/2})^{2n}}\ dr<\infty
\end{align}
when $n\geq 2$.

Hence $f \in W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R})$ but $f \not\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: As $\|f\|_{W^{1,n}}^n = \|f\|_{L^n}^n + \|\nabla f\|_{L^n}^n$, haven't you just shown that your counterexample is not an element of $W^{1,n}$?

Comment: @Neal What do you mean?

Comment: Ah sorry, that's the $L^1$ norm you evaluated, not the $L^n$. I think you have a typo in the last paragraph - should be "$f\notin L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$" not "$f\notin L^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$".

Comment: ahh... Yes. Thanks.